# Combine route and query parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angular-router

In Angular I have to process a route in the format

```
/sections/{id}?filter={filter}
```

i.e. I have a route parameter (`id`), and a query parameter (`filter`). Both parameters are optional, so all of these routes are valid and being listened to

```
/sections/{id}?filter={filter}
/sections?filter={filter}
/sections/{id}
/sections
```

When handling a route I need to call a potentially expensive service, providing the parameters given. I can subscribe to both the `params` and `queryParams` of the route, but I want only to call the service once per url change, avoiding any unneeded calls.

The problem is that when moving from `/sections/1?filter=active` to `/sections/2` both observables will trigger, and I cannot control which one will trigger first. On the other hand, when moving from `/sections/1?filter=active` to `/sections/1`, or from `/sections/1?filter=active` to `/sections/2?filter=active`, only one will be triggered.

Is there any sane way to know when the last subscription triggers, so that I can avoid sending unneeded server calls?

---

The test code so far looks something like:

```
constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: dataService) {

    this.activeRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        console.log("triggering route params subscription");
        this.section = params.get("id");
        this.dataService.runSlowQuery(this.section, this.filter);
    });

    this.activeRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((queryParams: ParamMap) => {
        console.log("triggering query params subscription");
        this.filter = queryParams.get("filter");
        this.dataService.runSlowQuery(this.section, this.filter);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Subscribe to router event

You can subscribe to router `events`. This will give you access to the [`UrlTree`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree) object which allows for more flexibility.

```
import { Router, UrlTree, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private router: Router) {}

...

let navigation = this.router.events
   .filter(navigation => navigation instanceof NavigationEnd)
   .map((navigation) => {
     let urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(navigation['url']);
     let queryParams = urlTree.queryParams;
     let segments = urlTree.root.children['primary'] ? urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments : null;
     return { queryParams: queryParams, segments: segments }
   });

navigation.subscribe((navigation) => { ... });
```

### 2. Make use of [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)

```
let params = this.activeRoute.paramMap;
let queryParams = this.activeRoute.queryParamMap;
let navigation = Observable
   .combineLatest(params, queryParams, (params, queryParams) => ({ params, queryParams }));

navigation.subscribe((navigation) => { ... });
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but this is a bit roundabout way of going about it.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Added another solution.

Comment: I think if I `combineLatest` params, queryParams, and NavigationEnd, I'll be able to both deterministically say when navigation ended, and have the data easily accessible.

Comment: `combineLatest` should take care of that for you. No need for NavigationEnd.