# Angular how to use combineLatest to combine routes and queries from website url bar

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, combinelatest

Im trying to get the route and queries from the url bar. The below code is from a tutorial by CodeWithMosh. I am getting compile error at the combineLatest method.

The error is as follow:

> (property) paramMap: Observable Argument of type '{
>   paramMap: Observable; queryParamMap: Observable;
>   }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'paramMap' does
>   not exist in type 'ObservableInput'

I am a newbie in angular and I'm not sure what does the error mean and I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176328/combine-route-and-query-parameters-in-angular) stack overflow answer but I still got the error. Thank you.

The full code is as below:

```
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { GithubFollowersService } from './../services/github-followers.service';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import 'rxjs/add/Observable/combineLatest';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
    import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
      selector: 'github-followers',
      templateUrl: './github-followers.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./github-followers.component.css']
    })
    export class GithubFollowersComponent implements OnInit {
      followers : any[];

      constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private service : GithubFollowersService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        const paramMap = this.route.paramMap;
        const queryParamMap = this.route.queryParamMap;

        combineLatest({
          paramMap, // error here
          queryParamMap
        })
        .subscribe(combined => {
          let id = combined[0].get('id');//the 0 means the 1st 1 which is paramMap from above
          let page = combined[1].get('page');

          this.service.getAll().subscribe(followers => this.followers = followers);
        });


      }

    }
```

Comment: [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/combineLatest) doesn't take an object containing observables.

Comment: What version of Angular and RxJS are you using? Your first two RxJS imports are not correct for the current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the current version of Angular/RxJS, your imports should look like this:

```
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

The error you see is incorrect syntax for combineLatest. It should look like this:

```
  combineLatest([
    paramMap,
    queryParamMap
  ])
```

Notice the `[]` instead of the `{}`

Also, it is a convention to suffix variables containing an Observable with a `$`.

From the github comments:

> Static version of `combineLatest` accepts either an array of
>   Observables or each Observable can be put directly as an argument.

Link here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/95bd8073e33c39a8f8d4ade8bf15c39a1154a879/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts

Comment: Isn't it better to also to use a `switchMap` here since these parameters might change from inside a component?

Comment: That could be difficult to discern without more information about the context of this code. Without that context, I just focused on the specifics of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `forkJoin` to execute a certain code when multiple subscription complete. A pseudo logic to do this is

```
forkJoin(
  paramMap.pipe(
    tap(res => {
      allParams["param1"] = res.get("param1");
    })
  ),
  queryParamMap.pipe(
    tap(res => {
      allParams["param1"] = res.get("param2");
    })
  )
).subscribe(res => {
  //call your service
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ditch the `{ }`:

```
        combineLatest(
          paramMap,
          queryParamMap
        )
        .subscribe(combined => {
```

No `{ }`, no `[ ]`, just list the streams to combine.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html